# When Monero is worth $10,000 will fees in xmr be the same or lower/higher?

Tags: transaction-fees, scalability

Currently (FEB-2021) a monero transaction fee is about .000015 XMR ($0.003 USD). When XMR reaches a higher price will these fees stay the same in XMR terms? If so won't that cause for concern like how ETH and BTC is now with outrageous fees of $5-$50 per transaction? Basically a scalability problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When XMR reaches a higher price will these fees stay the same in XMR terms?

Yes, they stay the same in XMR terms. I.e. XMR fee level is not based on any exchange rate.

> If so won't that cause for concern like how ETH and BTC is now with outrageous fees of $5-$50 per transaction? Basically a scalability problem.

No. The fee and scalability problem with Bitcoin happens because Bitcoin imposes a block size constraint which limits throughput, causes competition for block space and thus a fee market is present. When usage is high people are competing to get their transactions in the next block and thus pay higher fees. Monero doesn't have this problem and in fact with higher usage fees actually go *down* (in XMR terms).